# Does Mule ESB Supports Multi Tenancy

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-cluster

Hi I am working with Mule ESB and I just want to know that it supports Multi Tenancy Or  not ?

Comment: Can you specify how you'd like multi-tenancy to apply to Mule? I'm unclear what you're expecting here.

Comment: mean i will run only a single instance of my software and its able to serve multiple tenants independently

Comment: Each message processed by Mule is independent from the other, so I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: In addition to David's answer, each Mule application is also a tenant itself. So you possibilities are using content-based routing by inspecting each method in one application, or using separate apps for tenants that don't share the same OS process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mule Application server is like a servlet container. In fact quite similar to JBoss. So just like in any other app serer you can install different apps for different client.

However there is obviously a risk that one of your apps does something dodgy that for instance:
 - eats up all the memory, CPU, disk space
 - invokes a very bad program, like a groovy script that does a system.exit(); command
Or other.

So I guess the general answer is: As long as you know what applications are running in parallel you can run them. But it is definitely not a "hosting server" to rent web space on like a virtual host on Apache HTTPD.

Sebastian